# Getting Error - Not Enough subscripts or indices were specified in COBOL

Tags: arrays, cobol, subscript

I am getting an error while compiling COBOL module - 'Not enough subscripts or indices were specified for PREFER-VALUE of PREFERENCE of MQ82122A-DATA. A subscript or Index value of 1 was assumed for each missing subscript or index.'

**Code**

```
01 MQ82122A-DATA.
 03 UPDATE-PREFRENCES.
   05 UPDATE-AGREEMENT-PREF.
      07 PREFRENCES.
         10 PREFRENCE            OCCURS 10.
            13 CATEGORY                    PIC X(10).
            13 PREFRENCE-TYPE    OCCURS 5.
               15 PREFER-VALUE             PIC X(100).

MOVE DOCPREF1     TO PREFER-VALUE IN PREFERENCE IN MQ82122A-DATA(1).
MOVE DOCPREF2     TO PREFER-VALUE IN PREFERENCE IN MQ82122A-DATA(2).
```

Comment: How are `DOCPREF1` and `DOCPREF2` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `PREFERENCE` as a qualifier is confusing and may be unnecessary.

If `DOCPREF1` and `DOCPREF2` are defined as `PIC X(100)` then `PREFERENCE` as a qualifier is unnecessary and two subscripts must be used, the first for `PREFERENCE`, the second for `PREFERENCE-TYPE`.

If `DOCPREF1` and `DOCPREF2` are defined identically to a single occurrence of `PREFERENCE` then `IN PREFER-VALUE` should be removed from the `MOVE` statement and a single subscript for `PREFERENCE` should be used.

---

With spelling corrections and based on OP's "comment" as an answer (flagged and deleted), the solution was to add a second subscript similar to that given below in the `MOVE` statements.

```
   DATA DIVISION.
   01 DOCPREF1 PIC X(100).
   01 DOCPREF2 PIC X(100).
   01 MQ82122A-DATA.
    03 UPDATE-PREFERENCES.
      05 UPDATE-AGREEMENT-PREF.
         07 PREFERENCES.
            10 PREFERENCE            OCCURS 10.
               13 CATEGORY                    PIC X(10).
               13 PREFERENCE-TYPE    OCCURS 5.
                  15 PREFER-VALUE             PIC X(100).
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       MOVE DOCPREF1
           TO PREFER-VALUE IN PREFERENCE IN MQ82122A-DATA(1, 1).
       MOVE DOCPREF2
           TO PREFER-VALUE IN PREFERENCE IN MQ82122A-DATA(1, 2).
```

Comment: Good answer - the only thing missing is a sample of a working `MOVE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

`MOVE DOCPREF1     TO PREFER-VALUE IN PREFERENCE IN MQ82122A-DATA(1).`

PREFER-VALUE needs a subscript, it's in a group that occurs 5, inside the first preference from DATA(1).  Compiler gives you the first PREFER-VALUE within the ambiguous inner field reference.

I'd rather see

```
MOVE DOCPREF1 TO PREFER-VALUE IN MQ82122A-DATA(1,1)
MOVE DOCPREF2 TO PREFER-VALUE(1,2)
                       *> or (2,1) depending on what you mean.
```

Drop the INs beyond top level and just use the two subscripts, would be the recommendation. *The sample depends on the question Rick raised about the layout or PIC of the DOCPREF fields, and may be utterly incorrect.*

As an aside, GnuCOBOL won't compile those field references, as is.

```
prompt$ cobc subs.cob
subs.cob: in paragraph 'sample-main':
subs.cob:40: error: 'PREFER-VALUE IN PREFERENCE IN MQ82122A-DATA' is not defined
subs.cob:41: error: 'PREFER-VALUE IN PREFERENCE IN MQ82122A-DATA' is not defined
```

That may be a deficiency, but not by much in this case, I don't think.

Comment: No compiler can reference something that does not exists. The field is named `PREFRENCE`, not `PREFERENCE` :-)